# how to sort columns in ireport crosstab in a specific scheme

Tags: java, sorting, jasper-reports, crosstab

The following image shows my crosstab in ireport:

[image: crosstab]

I want to sort my columns in a specific order, knowing that in the crosstab data, i put a list of objects `List<ChampEtatAteliers>` with the following attributes :

```
public class ChampEtatAteliers {

    private String numero;
    private String denominationFr;
    private String etatEntreeSortie;

    public ChampEtatAteliers(String numero, String denominationFr, String etatEntreeSortie) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.denominationFr = denominationFr;
        this.etatEntreeSortie = etatEntreeSortie;
    }
}
```

the `etatEntreeSortie` is shown in the columns, the `denominationFr` is shown in the rows, and `numero` is used for the count in crosstab

```
String rapportLien = "/SituationEquipement.jasper";
Map parametres = new HashMap();
JRBeanCollectionDataSource data = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(atelierses);
```

in java I'm putting these objects in list `atelierses`  `List<ChampEtatAteliers>`, so is there any way to sort the columns in the list or in the crosstab ireport, my xml code on ireport is as follows:

```
<columnGroup name="nbreVehicule" height="66">
    <bucket order="Descending" class="java.lang.String">
        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{nbreVehicule}]]></bucketExpression>
        <orderByExpression><![CDATA[$V{MyOrderByField_measure}]]></orderByExpression>
    </bucket>
    <crosstabColumnHeader>
        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="85" height="66" uuid="2109b261-1b20-493a-b664-ce59731c4a20"/>
                <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="1" bottomPadding="1" rightPadding="1"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{nbreVehicule}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </cellContents>
    </crosstabColumnHeader>
    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
        <cellContents/>
    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
</columnGroup>
<measure name="MyOrderByField_measure" class="java.lang.Integer"  calculation="Nothing" >
    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{myOrderByField}]]></measureExpression>
</measure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jasper report the crosstab `columnGroup` can be sorted **ascending** or **descending** by setting the `order` attribute on the `bucket`

**Example**

```xml
<columnGroup name="GROUP" height="16" headerPosition="Center">
    <bucket order="Descending" class="java.lang.String">
        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{MyField}]]></bucketExpression>
    </bucket>
    .....
</columnGroup>
```

If you need a **user defined** order, you should use the `orderByExpression`

1. Define a measure for on what you like to order

   ```xml
   <measure name="myOrderByField_measure" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="First">
       <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{myOrderByField}]]></measureExpression>
   </measure>
   ```
2. Use the measure in `orderByExpression`

   ```xml
   <columnGroup name="GROUP" height="16" headerPosition="Center">
     <bucket class="java.lang.String">
       <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{myField}]]></bucketExpression>
       <orderByExpression><![CDATA[$V{myOrderByField_measure}]]></orderByExpression>
   </bucket>
   .....
   </columnGroup>
   ```

In your example this could be achieved by introducing a new field in the `ChampEtatAteliers` class example `private int myOrderByField;` and then via code setting it as needed.

**Another solution**, would be to return an own Object (class) as `MyField` and implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), that generates the desired order.

**EDIT:** WORK AROUND, OP CAN NOT MAKE THE `orderByExpression` work correctly.

Since the `myOrderByField` is unique (related 1 to 1) to the `nbreVehicule` he can use `myOrderByField` in the `bucketExpression`

```xml
<measure name="nbreVehicule_measure" class="java.lang.String">
   <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{nbreVehicule}]]></measureExpression>
</measure>

<columnGroup name="nbreVehicule" height="66">
   <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
     <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{myOrderByField}]]></bucketExpression>
   </bucket>
   ....
   <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{nbreVehicule_measure}]]></textFieldExpression>
   .....
</columnGroup>
```

Hence the `bucketExpression` does not need to be the same as the text displayed in the `crosstabColumnHeader`